# how do I tell gnu make where a header file is?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a simple C file, which compiles. I am now trying to add to it an outside header file located at

```
../../myotherdir/tbt/include
```

Here is my C file:

```
/* Hello World program */
#include<stdio.h>
#include "app.h"
main()
  {
      printf("Hello World");

  }
```

Here is my makefile:

```
headerdir = ../../mytree2/tlk/include
hello: hello.c **app.h** 
    gcc -I$(headerdir) hello.c -o hello
```

How do I get make to search for the headerfiles in myotherdir/tbt/include and add them to my project?

I updated the makefile as suggested by Mureinik. Thanks it worked. Now I get a different error stating that I do not have a rule to make app.h.

I found my error I think. I should not have added app.h as a prerequisite. I highlighted it in bold above. After removing that line, I got other errors, but it seems my make file works. Thanks Mureinik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gcc -o hello.o -I$(headerdir) hello.c
```

You don't need to specify  VPATH like that.
you can just change headerdir to include more header files. Eg.

```
headerdir = ../../myotherdir/tbt/include ../path/to/next/header/dir ../etc/etc
```

Comment: Thanks. your solution worked. Now it says I do not have a rule for building app.h. I did not know I have to build prerequisits also. Can you suggest a way to handle that? Perhaps I need to create a variable like src and modify my rule to an implicit one of building all src files?

Comment: That's because you're not compiling app.c.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-I` argument to set the location of additional headers:

```
hello: hello.c app.h 
    gcc -I${headerdir} hello.c -o hello
```